# Glitchy lines on screen of laptop

Tags: display, visual-artifacts

On my laptop screen I'm getting moving colourful lines which aren't disappearing. What can be problem?

On external monitor all is OK.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=woEe9wgciuo

[image]

P.S. External monitor I can use only when windows logo appears, before that I cannot, for example to enter bios.

Comment: Update your drivers. You appear to be looking at an Intel applicaiton, but can I assume this issue occurs with everything (even when booting up)?

Comment: Yea, when screen shows up artefacts appears immediately.

Comment: Did yo uupdate your drivers? It sounds like the screen is bust (or a cable). The only option I *think* you'll have is to send it a repair shop (or attempt it yourself, at your own risk)

Answer (score 2):

I'm running on the assumption this is the machine booting, and therefore before the OS has loaded.

Looks like your laptop panel has failed or received damage, especially if you are getting a correct video output from an external screen. It is also possible the cable has been damaged, they can get caught in hinges, or become loose.

You could try checking the integrity of the cable and re-seating it. If this appears okay, to test the panel you would need to get the panel replaced. These are usually fairly generic but there are some exceptions (LCD panels will have a backlight and an inverter which may have custom connectors/two backlight bulbs. LED panels have no inverter, so you must use the correct type of panel).

Your best bet is to take it to a reputable shop for them to test another panel in and replace if required, as depending on the laptop model this can be quite a tear-down.